# how to use if exist update else insert in mysql 5.0?

Tags: mysql

I got this error
MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name =  'Smith' AND id =4) THEN

UPDA' at line 1

when I try this code

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name =  'Smith' AND id =4) THEN 
UPDATE table_name SET name =  'Test', tele =45 WHERE id =4 ELSE 
INSERT INTO table_name( id, name, address, tele ) 
VALUES ( 5,  'John',  'NY', 56 );
```

The insert into on duplicate key require some unique key which I don't have in my table.

Any help, please? I'm stuck with this for a few days.

Comment: The MySQL syntax requires the unique key. You can always create an unique index which will give you the same INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE behaviour else your code could lead to updating multiple records at once.

Answer (score 0):

Use `on duplicate key insert`.

Start by defining a unique index on the table.  Actually, if `id` is a primary key, then you can skip this.

I presume that you want something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name( id, name, address, tele ) 
    VALUES ( 5,  'John',  'NY', 56 )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = 'Test', tele = 45;
```

This isn't *exactly* your logic, but I think the behavior is more reasonable.  Your version would insert a duplicate row with `4, john`, if `4, <anything not Smith>` is in the table.

Comment: I produced this table for testing, in my company database table I don't have a unique primary key, so I can not use the ON DUPLICATE KEY command.

Comment: @Ben2014 . . . You do not need a primary key for `on duplicate key`.  Any unique key(s) will do.